# Destruir componente React (Unmounting Component)

Tags: javascript, html, herança, react, react-dom

Gostaria de saber como faço pra destruir um componente com React ao clicar em um botão. Encontrei uma saída, porém na minha concepção é bem "gambiarrosa". Tenho um state chamado `show` e quando click em fechar modifico o valor do `this.state.show` para false, no método render() utilizo um if ternário para renderizar o componente ou não dependendo do valor `this.state.show`.

#### MyComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';

class MyComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show:true,
    };
  }

  closeComponent(){
      console.log("Destruir componente");
      var x = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
      console.log(x);
      //ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.container);
      this.setState({ show: false });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.show ?
      <div className="MyComponent">
        <h1>Mostrar componente</h1>
        <FontAwesome name="window-close-o" onClick={this.closeComponent.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
      : null
    );
  }

}

export default MyComponent;
```

Essa é realmente a única saída pro que eu preciso fazer?

#### ComponentFather.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ComponentFather.css';
import MyComponent from '../MyComponent/MyComponent'

class ComponentFather extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "Adicionar Categoria",
      key: 0,
      matchs: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){

  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.state);
  }

  buttonClicked(){
    var mat = this.state.matchs;
    this.state.key ++;
    mat.push(<Match key={this.state.key}/>);
    console.log(mat);
    this.setState({
      matchs: mat
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ComponentFather">
        <h1>Events Information</h1>
        <MyComponent></MyComponent>
        <MyComponent></MyComponent>
        <MyComponent></MyComponent>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ComponentFather;
```

#### MainComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ComponentFather from '../ComponentFather/ComponentFather';
import Streaming from '../Streaming/Streaming';

//import {Grid, Row, Col, Clearfix} from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ComponentFather />
        <Streaming />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './components/App/App';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('main-container')
);
```

Comment: Vi agora o teu edit. Dá-me ideia que o teu código é adaptado e não o código real. Duas perguntas: Esses `MyComponent` são sempre 3 ou isso é dinâmico? Outra pergunta, o `ComponentFather` sabe o estado de cada `MyComponent`?

Comment: Coloquei os 3 amarrados apenas para ter uma representação de como vai ser, mas o correto é ser dinâmico. Quanto a sua outra pergunta eu não sei responder. Iniciei os estudos no React esses dias, to devorando a documentação pra vê se clareia mais as coisas. A ideia é a seguinte, o ComponentFather vai carregar uma lista de objetos do backend e pra cada objeto da lista eu vou criar um MyComponent passando o objeto como parametro, as propriedades do objeto serão todas exibidas no MyComponent e dentro do MyComponent vou ter a opção de destruir aquele componente ao clicar em um determinado botão....

Comment: Ok. Se o `ComponentFather` guardar o estado de cada `MyComponent` ele saberá se deve mostrar ou não um dado `MyComponent`. Essa parece-me a maneira mais correta. Estás a usar flux? Mobx? nenhum deles? Daqui a pouco vou dar um exemplo para ver se é isso que procuras

Comment: Por enquanto ainda estou apenas na parte estática mas pretendo utilizar o flux, pelo que li até agora me aprece o mais viável. Porém tenho que pesquisar um pouco mais fundo porque a comunicação vai ser via socket. Pelo que vi na sua resposta é justamente isso que preciso. Muito obrigado pela força que você ta me dando. Só mais outra coisa... Tem algum material que você recomenda pra turbinar meu aprendizado a cerca do React?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui entretanto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wsg3aSvPCXE

Comment: Mais uma duvida para o exemplo que estou a montar: esses `MyComponent` são uma representação de quê? uma array? uma lista da BD? chaves de um objeto?

Comment: Chaves de um objeto

Comment: Editei a resposta, como estás a fazer funciona bem. Dependendo da lógica do elemento pai podes ter uma array com elementos filhos não fazer render via "pai", mas como tens funciona bem. Dá uma olhada no meu jsFiddle, pode ser util para testes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira de desmontar um componente é com [ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode). Esse método aceita o elemento DOM em que o componente está montado. Se não tens uma referência do elemento podes passar `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode` como argumento.

Assim o teu método para destruir o componente poderia ser:

```
closeComponent() {
    console.log("Destruir componente");
    var container = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode;
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
}
```

Se esse componente estiver inserido noutro, o melhor seria esconder o elemento via componente pai. Dependendo da lógica por detrás do `state` do componente.

No teu caso, como estás a fazer é válido, dessa maneira o componente `MyComponent` fica responsável de guardar o seu próprio estado. E ficaria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/5gjapobx/

Comment: Não rolou... warning.js:36 Warning: unmountComponentAtNode(): The node you're attempting to unmount was rendered by React and is not a top-level container. Instead, have the parent component update its state and rerender in order to remove this component.

Comment: @LuKsSys pensava que era um componente isolado, assim preciso que mostres o componente onde esse está inserido para ajudar...

Comment: Vou editar o código acima e mostrar o código onde ele está inserido

Comment: Agradeço pelo ajuda, resolveu meu problema.